# how to convert string to byte[]

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, byte

When I translate txt file to byte operation I encounter some problems.

- Example `little` is the only words in `test.txt.
- The result of encoded by `ascii` code is `6c6974746c65` .
- I want to execute byte operation like `data[0x2]|data[0x3]<<8 means 0x74 | (0x74)<<8 =0x7474`.

  ```
  f = open('test.txt','rb')
  output = f.read() 
  f.close()
  file_size = len(output)
  print output,type(output)
  output_ascii = output.encode("hex")
  print output_ascii , type(output_ascii) , len(output_ascii)
  print output_ascii[0],output_ascii[1]`
  ```

Result

```
little ('type str')  
6c6974746c65 (type 'str') 12  
6 c
```

I would like to get output_ascii[0] = `0x6c , output_ascii[1] = 0x69 ...etc`

How should I modify?

Answer (score 0):

```
byte = ''
total_byte = []

with open('test.txt','rb') as f:
    output = f.read() 
    print output, type(output)
    for ele in output:
        byte = ele.encode("hex")
        total_byte.append(byte)
        print byte ,type(byte)

print total_byte[0], total_byte[1]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.  This will help other people with a similar problem use your answer.